# I can't make match two relations in a Pig script with timestamps

Tags: apache-pig

I have two relations in a Pig script (let's call it A and B). A and B have both two fields for each tuple containing a timestamp (tsa and tsb for example) and and another value (a for A and b for B). The order of each relation is so that timestamps are increasing. For the relation A, the difference between timestamps of two consecutive tuples is 5 seconds. For the relation B, this difference is unknown, it can be 1 second as well as 30 minutes (random events).

Here is an example of the relation A (the value "a" is between 100 and 500):

```
(1376092800, 112) 
(1376092805, 200)
(1376092810, 323)
(1376092815, 365)
(1376092820, 500)
(1376092825, 122)
(1376092830, 222)
(1376092835, 456)
(1376092840, 100)
(1376092845, 277)
```

Here is an example of the B relation (the value "b" is between 1000 and 4000):

```
(1376092800, 3120) 
(1376092822, 1200)
(1376092827, 4000)
(1376092830, 1325)
(1376092870, 1700)
(1376093000, 1000)
(1376094532, 2233)
(1376095641, 2460)
(1376095646, 1378)
```

For each tuple of the B relation, I would like to match every A tuple with the same timestamp or with a upper one (but lower than the next B tuple). With the previous example. I would like to get:

```
(1376092800, 3120) -> (1376092800, 3120, 112, 200, 323, 365, 500) 
(1376092822, 1200) -> (1376092822, 1200, 122)
(1376092827, 4000) -> (1376092827, 4000)
(1376092830, 1325) -> (1376092830, 1325, 222, 456, 100, 277)
(1376092870, 1700) -> ...
```

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Please share what you have tried already and why you are having trouble.

Comment: Actually, I don't really see how to start. I would like to make something like a "join" but as timestamps are most of the time different it doesn't seem easy to do. I thought I could make a UDF to change A timestamps so that I could make them match with B ones more easily (with a join for example) but as B timestamps are "random", it seems to be a dead-end...

Comment: @MarAja Yeah, this is not an easy question. How large is the data? This is likely going to require a `GROUP B ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a CROSS of the two relations and then FILTER the result by A.timestamp >= B.timestamp. Then GROUP BY A.timestamp.

I think that gets you the result you want.